# Drilling thru cement floor with radiant heat flow below

Tags: flooring

I want to drill screws through a 4 inch cement floor to install a cement plate or some form of metal bracket to hold a 6"X 6" vertical support beam that will help to support a horizontal beam. My problem is radiant heat (copper piping) below the cement slab.
How precise are those thermal electronic devices to pinpoint the copper tubing to avoid penetrating the copper piping ?? Or is there another way to stabilize the vertical beam to the cement floor ?

Comment: Is a 4" slab with copper pipes underneath enough of a footer to support whatever those beams are supporting?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this floor on grade? Must you go all the way through the slab? (That asked, this may require hiring a structural engineer.)

Comment: If you are relocating a bearing post, concrete floors are laid out prior to pouring the floor as to where the bearing points need to be and a thickened slab is created in those areas to act as a footing for bearing and thicker for strength. Even if it is a bearing wall with a continuous plate, the slab is still thickened.

Answer (score 3):

A thermal imaging camera will be able to pinpoint the location of the pipes, I have a flir camera that attaches to my phone it will even show wiring that has bad connections they cost around 200 and up and are a great troubleshooting tool for a DIY person. I have used my camera to find leaks where I could not detect water from the roof until it ran down a wall and made a wet spot on sheetrock. I have used it for sealing up duct work, and for electrical inspections. Finding the location of the radient pipe work would be another great use for this tool. When the heat is running you would take a image and the hot zone will be where the pipe is. Based on the work I have used my camera for I believe you could pinpoint your pipes within a 1/4" or even closer depending on how thick the concrete is above the pipe.